# PHP - Remove '.' and '..' from values fetched from directory files

Tags: php, directory

I am using this code in order to get a list files from directory:

```
$dir = '/restosnapp_cms/images/'; 
if ($dp = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir)) { 
    $files = array(); 
    while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== false) { 
        if (!is_dir($dir . $file)) { 
            $files[] = $file; 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dp); 
} else { 
    exit('Directory not opened.'); 
}
```

I want to get rid of the values '.' and '..'.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to do this? Thank you. :)

Comment: Of course, you can filter it before outputting. There are many array functions that can help one way or another. Or you can just put an `if` in the loop and only output the name if it is not `.` or `..`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier?  `$files = array_filter(glob("$dir/*"), 'is_file');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check for them first:

```
while ($file = readdir($p)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: +1 - I have had some cases in which I later wanted to add more filenames that should not be listed, in that case an `in_array($file, array('.', '..', ...))` is sometimes easier.

Answer (score 1):

[`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) is much more fun than *dir functions:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir);
foreach($dir as $file) {
   if (!$file->isDir() && !$file->isDot()) {
      $files[] = $file->getPathname();
   }
}
```

But the bottomline is regardless of which way you do it, you need to use a conditional.